# Why iPhone app adhoc distributed is not installed on device?

Tags: iphone, installation, itunes

I distributed iPhone app with adhoc distribution and I tried installing this app on my device. It's already installing and working fine on another device with iPod (OS 4.0), iPad (4.3.1), iPhone(5) via MAC, But It's not done iPhone with 4.2.1 OS while trying with windows iTunes.

Did I miss the installation of provisioning profile on the device? I tried installing only the ipa to the device.

Here is the error message
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the provisioning file as well.

See this guide: http://www.innerfence.com/howto/install-iphone-application-ad-hoc-distribution

I highly recommend [TestFlightApp](https://testflightapp.com/) for beta testing and ad hoc distribution.

Comment: +1 on the recommendation of TestFlightApp. It makes these things so much easier!

Answer (score 1):

.ipa does have the embedded provisioning profile and the case where the provisioning does lack, I'm sure atlease "UNKNOWN ERROR" is not raised. It simply generates a message which tells the reason of not installing the app on device.

Might be windows/iTunes internal error (not related to your app).
Needed to be further investigated.